# Percentage Computation in C

Tags: c

I am trying to compute a percentage that calculates the number of home team wins but keep receiving 0 when I know the values I am dividing by are correct.

I've tried calculating it with values that are pointers and then have the percentage outputted by a pointer, but nothing seems to work.

```
//update function
void update(int * totalGames, int * homeTeamWins, double * homeTeamWinPercentage, int difference) {

*totalGames = *totalGames + 1;
if (difference >= 0) 
    *homeTeamWins = *homeTeamWins + 1;

homeTeamWinPercentage = (*homeTeamWins / *totalGames);

}

//summary function
void summary(int totalGames, int homeTeamWins, double homeTeamWinPercentage) {

//* homeTeamWinPercentage = (homeTeamWins / totalGames);

printf("\n Of the %d total games, %d home teams won, resulting in a %d%.2f%% home team win percentage\n", totalGames, homeTeamWins, homeTeamWinPercentage);

}



// in my main
void main() { 
        ...
        ...
    while (!feof(file1)) {

    output(homeTeam, visitingTeam, difference);
    update(&totalGames, &homeTeamWins, &homeTeamWinPercentage, difference);
}

summary(totalGames, homeTeamWins, homeTeamWinPercentage);
system("pause");
}
```

Of the 13 total games, 7 home teams won, resulting in a -8589934600.00% home team win percentage.

I can tell it is pointing to somewhere in memory. I have gotten it to print 0.00% for the percentage but that still does not help me.

I am trying to acheive homeTeamWins / totalGames = homeTeamWinPercentage (7/13=53.18%) but am having trouble.

Comment: ^^^ That, also: [while(feof) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I did a little research myself and found this [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: It would be more sensible, I think, if the `update()` function returned the percentage rather than working via a pointer argument.  That's perhaps subjective, but I'd make that argument.

Comment: Your printf should be generating warnings. Never ignore the warnings until you understand them!

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in this line:

> homeTeamWinPercentage = (*homeTeamWins / *totalGames);

The expression `(*homeTeamWins / *totalGames);` will perform integer division and return an integer.

Instead use:

```
((double) *homeTeamWins / (double) *totalGames)
```

So, your update function should look like this:

```
void update(int * totalGames, int * homeTeamWins, double * eTeamWinPercentage,
            int difference)
{
    *totalGames = *totalGames + 1;
    if (difference >= 0) 
        *homeTeamWins = *homeTeamWins + 1;

    *homeTeamWinPercentage = ((double) *homeTeamWins / (double) *totalGames) * 100;
}
```

P.S: Just noticed you're using very strange way to print the output.
Use the following line, just works fine :)

```
printf("Of %d total Games, %d home teams won, percentage: %0.2f", totalGames, homeTeamWins, percent);
```

Hope it helps :))

Comment: Output: Of the 13 total games, 7 home teams won, resulting in a -13215283990.00% home team win percentage

Comment: That is my output after implementing your "fix"

Comment: Btw, you should probably be multiplying by 100 if you're trying to get percentage :/

Comment: @yayhe I've updated the answer (Tested this time) :)

Comment: The alternative fix for the percentage, if you actually only want an integer percentage anyway is to perform the *100 first on the dividand. In fact the quick fix to implicitly get the cast to double is to multiply the dividand by 100.0